# Deinstall Visual Studio Community

Tags: visual-studio

I got a new drive and wanted to uninstall Visual Studio Community from my `C:` drive and reinstall it on the `D:` drive. However I did it wrong and just deleted all folders related to Visual Studio 2019 and didn't use the proper way to deinstall it. Now the Visual Studio Installer won't properly uninstall because it can't find some files that it needs I guess. And now the Visual Studio Community does not appear in available so I cant even install completely from scratch. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio is it? And what Windows platform are you using?

Comment: my first approach would be to install it again to its original location (or "repair" if it works), and then to uninstall properly

Comment: *However I did it wrong and just deleted all folders related to Visual Studio 2019* -- So you never expected a huge product such as Visual Studio to do things like --- update registry settings?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Community 2019 on Windows 10. The thing is I cant install it. I would provide a screenshot of the installer but that is not possible here. Also I only have the options repeat or remove. But both ways it doesnt work.

Comment: What are the update registry settings and why would help to update them? No I expected it to recognize Visual Studio Community is no longer installed and then I could reinstall it. However I already stated I did something wrong and I know that. The only question is how do i fix it?

Comment: @Nicky You have the options to repeat or remove, and your question suggests you tried "remove". Did you try "repeat"? Also, where is this "available" in which you expect to see Visual Studio Community?

Comment: Have you checked [the documentation for troubleshooting installation issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/troubleshooting-installation-issues?view=vs-2019)?

Comment: @JaMitT7 I said i tried it both ways and it didn't work. And by availabe I mean there are to tabstrips in the Visual Studio installer. One says available. Right now there is the enterprise and professional version. And in the installed version is the community version with the setup error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so following the process that is documented in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/remove-visual-studio?view=vs-2019 I ran the cleanup tool and now I am able to reinstall the Microsoft Visual studio just like I did before. Thank you for answering!